# filter inside dplyr's summarise

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I want to use `filter` or similar function inside `summarise` from `dplyr` package. So I've got a dataframe (e.g. `mtcars`) where I need to group by factor (e.g. `cyl`) and then calculate some statistics and a percentage of total `wt` for every `cyl` type —> `wt.pc`.

The question is how can I subset/filter `wt` column inside `summarise` function to get a percentage but without last `10` rows?

I've tried this code but it returns `NA`:(

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(wt = round(sum(wt)),
            wt.pc = sum(wt) * 100 / sum(mtcars[, 6]),
            wt.pc.short = sum(wt[1:22]) * 100 / sum(mtcars[1:22, 6]),
            drat.max = round(max(drat)))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
    cyl    wt wt.pc wt.pc.short drat.max
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1     4    25  24.3          NA        5
2     6    22  21.4          NA        4
3     8    56  54.4          NA        4
```

wt.pc.short — % of sum(`wt`) for every `cyl` for shorter dataframe `mtcars[1:22,]`

Comment: `head(x,n=-10)` gives all but the last 10 values in a vector `x`, but one group (`cyl==6`) in `mtcars` has only 7 values, so that won't work. (Your `1:22` is missing the point of `dplyr`'s grouping.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(wt_new = round(sum(wt)), # note the change in name here!
            wt.pc = sum(wt) * 100 / sum(mtcars[, 6]),
            wt.pc.short = sum(wt[id<23]) * 100 / sum(mtcars[1:22, 6]),
            drat.max = round(max(drat)))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
    cyl wt_new wt.pc wt.pc.short drat.max
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1     4     25  24.3        22.7        5
2     6     22  21.4        25.8        4
3     8     56  54.4        51.6        4
```

The important part here is that when you assign `wt` in the call to `summarize`, all subsequent references to `wt` will take the previously assigned `wt`, not the original `wt`. A statement such as `wt[1:22]` is thus somewhat problematic. You can see this here:

```
mean(mtcars[,"mpg"])
# [1] 20.09062
var(mtcars[,"mpg"])
# [1] 36.3241
mtcars %>% summarise(var_before = var(mpg),  
                     mpg = mean(mpg), 
                     var_after = var(mpg))

#  var_before      mpg var_after
# 1    36.3241 20.09062        NA
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution and explanation. BTW is there a better way to calculate the percentage? I was surprised by your comment in the 7th row

Comment: No, that is pretty much how to do it in this case. Anything else would be a different percentage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this. First we calculate the row number within the group, if `max(row_number) > 10` then we have enough observations to remove the last 10 rows, in which case we filter to `max(ID)-9` (i.e. remove the last 10 rows), otherwise `ID==ID` returns true and doesn't remove anything.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(if (max(ID) > 10) ID < (max(ID) - 9) else ID == ID)
```